# I can't use Close(); to close a form with code but i can use Show(); to show it with code

Tags: c#

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            Form1.Show();
        }
        else if(!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            Form1.Close();
        }
    }
```

I cant close Form1 using Form1.Close(); because when i try it doesn't close the form but i can show the form by typing Form1.Show(); which i find strange. I have also tried using Form1.Hide(); and it doesn't work.

Comment: The opposite of `Form1.Show()` is `Form1.Hide()`

Comment: I'll give you the fact that the documentation for Close isn't all that clear, but some quick googling should have pointed you in the right direction...

Comment: Form1.Hide doesn't work for me either and i have used this method before but for some reason it doesn't work for me right now. Im going to look at the code in the Form1 to see if i have done something wrong.

Comment: @Bryan: What do you mean "nothing happens"? If you haven't shown the form, how do you know it hasn't closed? For that matter, why do you need to close it if it was never shown?

Comment: The Form1 is showing and i want to close it but i can't close it with Form1.Close(); but i can show it with Form1.Show();

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new Form in every eventhandler firing. Move creation of `Form1 Form1 = new Form1();` outside of the event handler and store variable to it in your form class. After that calling Form1.Show/Hide should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            Form1.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Form1.Hide();
        }
    }
```